# How to delete rows fast if they have empty values at specific columns in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

below is a code that checks if the cells at columns [G, H, J] are empty and delete the row where the the condition is true.
Nevertheless, the runtime of the code below is extremely slow, needs approx 15 minutes per 1500 table entries.
is there any way to optimise it ?
can I hash the rows that meet the condition below and then delete them all at once?

P.S: the original code can be found here https://gist.github.com/dDondero/285f8fd557c07e07af0e which I adapted it to my use case.

```
function deleteRows() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var lastRow =sheet.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow() + 1;
    var values = rows.getValues();
    var row;
    var rowsDeleted = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
      row = values[i];
      if (row[9] == '' && row[7] == '' && row[6] == ''
     ) {
        sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
        rowsDeleted++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try:

```
function DeleteEmptyRows() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const values = sheet.getDataRange()
                      .getValues()
                      .filter(row => row[9] !== '' && row[7] !== '' && row[6] !== '')

  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent()

  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
              .setValues(values)                      

}
```

If you have any background colors attached to rows, let me know and I can make an adjustment for you.

This code will filter out all rows with the empty cells specified, clear the sheet, and then set the values.

Comment: Thanks for providing the script, Neverthless it is throwing the following exception:                  Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 377 but the range has 1.

Comment: @KhaledGhazi Fixed! Sorry about that.

Comment: @KhaledGhazi My pleasure! Let me know if you need any further help

Comment: I am facing the problem that some entries are deleted even being valid, is there a way to assert if length of `row[6] && row[7]` the same in the filtered and the original sheet ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Delete rows

```
function deleteRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues().filter(r => !(!r[6] || !r[7] || !r[9]));
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error message **TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**