# Speed Up row deletion on apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made this code to remove empty rows based on if a column is blank, the code is running and doing what it needs to do, however it's taking more than 10 minutes to delete data from a sheet that has more than 15k rows of data, is there a way to speed this up?

```
function deleteEmptyRowsAll() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getDisplayValues();
  for (i = data.length - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
    if (data[i][0] === '') {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: the question is not answered as the post [How to delete rows fast if they have empty values at specific columns in Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447883/how-to-delete-rows-fast-if-they-have-empty-values-at-specific-columns-in-google) clears the content of the row instead of deleting the entire row.

Comment: `clears the content of the row` What makes you say that?

Comment: The problem with the answers are what if the row contains formulas and what if the blanks are intermittentantly spaced with in the data range.

Comment: yeah clears the content instead of deleting the empty row, so basically the code is doing a clear content instead of removing the row completely out of the sheet

Comment: If the linked question doesn't help, please briefly describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet including some sample data and formulas if they are used. P.S. There are already several questions about deleting rows faster.

Comment: Also please clarify why do you need to delete the rows instead of clearing the content. Does the rows have formatting, comments, notes, or other stuff that should be removed besides the row values?

Comment: It doesn't just clear content. It clears everything and re-adds  only what is needed.

Comment: Are there formulas in these rows?  How interspersed are the rows that need to be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code uses the `SpreadsheetApp` API. The reason it runs slowly is that it makes a separate call to delete each row individually. To delete rows more efficiently through that API, group consecutive rows into batches and delete such row batches each in one go, like this:

```
/**
* Deletes all rows in Sheet1 where the value in column B2:B is blank.
*/
function deleteRowsWhereColumnBIsBlank() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const column = ss.getRange('Sheet1!B2:B');
  const condition = (row) => row[0] === '';
  ss.toast(`Deleting rows...`);
  const numDeletedRows = deleteRowsConditionally_(column, condition);
  ss.toast(`Deleted ${numDeletedRows} rows.`);
}


/**
* Deletes all rows where a condition closure returns true.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} range The range to look at.
* @param {Function} condition A closure {String[]} that determines whether a row should be deleted.
* @return {Number} The number of rows deleted.
*/
function deleteRowsConditionally_(range, condition) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 8 September 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73651127/13045193
  const rowStart = range.getRow();
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  const rowsToDelete = [];
  values.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    if (condition(row)) {
      rowsToDelete.push(rowStart + rowIndex);
    }
  });
  deleteRows_(range.getSheet(), rowsToDelete);
  return rowsToDelete.length;
}


/**
* Deletes from a sheet the rows whose row numbers are given in an array.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A spreadsheet sheet where to delete rows.
* @param {Number[]} rowsToDelete The rows to delete, identified by 1-indexed row numbers.
* @return {Number} The count of delete operations done, i.e., number of the consecutive row runs deleted from the sheet.
*/
function deleteRows_(sheet, rowsToDelete) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 21 August 2022
  const rowNumbers = rowsToDelete.filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index);
  const runLengths = getRunLengths_(rowNumbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
  for (let i = runLengths.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sheet.deleteRows(runLengths[i][0], runLengths[i][1]);
  }
  return runLengths.length;
}


/**
* Counts consecutive numbers in an array and returns a 2D array that
* lists the first number of each run and the number of items in each run.
*
* The numbers array [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 5, 4] will get
* the result [[1, 3], [5, 1], [8, 2], [11, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1]].
*
* For best results, sort the numbers array like this:
* const runLengths = getRunLengths_(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
* Note that duplicate values in numbers will give duplicates in result.
*
* @param {Number[]} numbers The numbers to group into runs.
* @return {Number[][]} The numbers grouped into runs, or [] if the array is empty.
*/
function getRunLengths_(numbers) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 31 May 2021
  if (!numbers.length) {
    return [];
  }
  return numbers.reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
    if (!index || value !== 1 + numbers[index - 1]) {
      accumulator.push([value]);
    }
    const lastIndex = accumulator.length - 1;
    accumulator[lastIndex][1] = (accumulator[lastIndex][1] || 0) + 1;
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}
```

For even better performance, use the Sheets API as demonstrated by Tanaike in this thread and at [Delete specific columns in Google App Script FAST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72602266/13045193).

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your showing script.
- You want to reduce the process cost of `sheet.deleteRow(i + 1)`.

Unfortunately, when `sheet.deleteRow()` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. In this case, how about using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used, I thought that the process cost can be reduced a little.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function deleteEmptyRowsAll() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Please set your sheet name.
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var values = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  var requests = values.reduce((ar, [b], i) => {
    if (b == "") {
      ar.push({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: "ROWS" } } });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

- When this script is run, the column "B" in the data range is checked. When the column "B" is empty, the rows are deleted using Sheets API.
- From `var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getDisplayValues();`, if you want to check all rows except for the data range, please modify `var values = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();` to `var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getDisplayValues();`.
- If you want to check rows in the data range, you can also modify `var values = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();` to `var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(), "'Sheet1'!B1:B").values;`. By this, I thought that the process cost might be able to be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function lfunko() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().filter(e => e[1] != '');
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, the code does indeed works however what is does is that it clears the rows of data and what I need is to delete the entire row not only clear it contents

Comment: I just ran it and it deletes all of the rows where column B is empty and returns them to data then it clears the sheet and rewrites the entire array of data.  This is definitely the fastest way to delete rows.