# Finding Non Matching Values in 2 Arrays from Google Sheets with Apps Script

Tags: arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script

Need some help

Im trying to find where a invoice number does not match in a different sheet but cant seem to get it to work.

Basically if the invoice number in main is not found in the working sheet (columns for both sheet invoice number is in D) then we can delete that row from main.

Should be quite straight forwards, can do this easily in google sheets to highlight/ or using COUNTIF but getting stick with my nbeginner JS Skills

```
function removeRows() {
const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()


const main = ss.getSheetByName('Main')
const mainData = main.getDataRange().getValues()
const mainLastRow = main.getDataRange().getLastRow()

const working = ss.getSheetByName('Workings')
const workingData = working.getDataRange().getValues()
const workingLastRow = working.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).length
const workingInvNo = working.getRange(1,4,workingLastRow,1).getValues() //was trying to use this but couldnt get this to work



//Logger.log(mainLastRow)

for (let j=0;j<mainLastRow;j++){
var invNo = mainData [j][3]

for (let row =0;row<=workingLastRow;row++){

var winvNo = workingData [j][3]

if(invNo !== winvNo){

Logger.log(row)
main.deleteRows(row)
}}}}
```

### Solution Update

I figured out how to do the task using index.Of . I had a few other challenges when it came to deleting the rows. See my Code below with the comments inbetween. Hope this helps someone else.

```
function removeRows() {
const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

//Value we are looking up against (i.e creating an Index)
const working = ss.getSheetByName('Workings')
const workingLastRow = working.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).length
const workingInvValues = working.getRange(1,4,workingLastRow,1).getValues()
const workingInvNos = workingInvValues.map(function(a){return a[0]}) // This was the step I needed to return each value of the array. need to understand .map more

//value we are looking up
const main = ss.getSheetByName('Main')
const mainLastRow = main.getDataRange().getLastRow()
const mainData = main.getRange(2,1,mainLastRow,4).getValues()

//empty array to but the row values
var rowsToDelete=[]

//Loop through each of the values
for (let j=0;j<mainLastRow-1;j++){
var invNo = mainData [j][3]

var match = workingInvNos.indexOf(invNo) // This looks up the index position of inv No

if(match <0){
var row=j+2 //this adjustment is needed because the data range of the main is starting from row 2
rowsToDelete.push(row)

}
}
//the deleteRow() function must be done after the array of all the rows has been iterated. Importantly it must start from the bottom or the value of the row changes with each loop when deleting from the top. 
for (r=rowsToDelete.length-1;r>=0;r--){
  var rowToDelete = rowsToDelete [r]
  main.deleteRow(rowToDelete)

}
}
```

Comment: Provide debugging details as written in [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to put your existing `countif()` function in column `Z2:Z`, and use a script to delete rows where the count is zero, like this:

```
/**
* Deletes all rows in 'Main' where the value in column Z2:Z contains a zero.
*/
function deleteRowsWhereColumnZIsZero() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const column = ss.getRange('Main!Z2:Z');
  const condition = (row) => row[0] === '0';
  ss.toast(`Deleting rows...`);
  const numDeletedRows = deleteRowsConditionally_(column, condition);
  ss.toast(`Deleted ${numDeletedRows} rows.`);
}
```

You can find `deleteRowsConditionally_()` and its helper functions at [Speed Up row deletion on apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73657633/13045193).

Comment: Yes I know that this is possible but I am looking to use the script function with a statement like index.of or compare values of arrays. More for my learning on how to code

Comment: See the link I posted for an example of how to do that. To learn more, look at the resources listed at [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).